# Is it possible to compile "import * AS X from 'X'" to "import X from 'X'"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a typescript script shared by `reactJS` and `react-native`.
The script imports some modules like this:

```
import * as axios from "axios";
import * as URIJS from "urijs";
```

In the react-native project, due to a framework requirement, the tsconfig needs to use `"module": "ES2015"` instead of `commonjs`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES2015",
        "target": "es6",
        .....
    },
}
```

I look at the compiled JS script, those two imports remain intact:

```
import * as axios from "axios";
import * as URIJS from "urijs";
```

Is there a way to turn these two imports into

```
import axios from "axios";
import URIJS from "urijs";
```

in the compiled JS script?

Because it will not work at runtime. It seems like it will import the entire object instead of a class, for example, when I run 
`let uri = new URIJS("someurl")`

it will throw this error:

```
TypeError: URIJS is not a constructor
```

Comment: do you mean: `import URI from "urijs";` and `let uri = new URI("someurl")`? [https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs)